# Facing issue with ubuntu re installation.16.04

Tags: gui

I faced issue with gui of Ubuntu and had to re install the OS. I retried a couple of times but the installation is stuck somewhere.

[image]

Need help at least to access my windows 10 . I am lost because it is giving grub error if I just restart my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Ubuntu bootable device like CD or pen drive and reinstall Ubuntu, Use universal pen drive bootable application for creating bootable media. 
If you only want to access your windows drive then install any version of Ubuntu and update the grub file.

Comment: Tried USB installer. But facing issue with it also.

Comment: download a fresh Ubuntu ISO file and create a bootable pen drive with universal pen drive bootable it will work definitely .